# if statements with classes in Python

Tags: python-3.x, oop, if-statement

I am making a small command prompt menu program. The User selects a letter option and the code take them to a small set of code that that makes specific calculations for them.

I have gotten the menu to work. However when I run `C` for Distributors nothing prints. What should I change?

```
def main():

    variable_to_cause_loop = "Y"

    while  variable_to_cause_loop == "Y":

        print ('A: Accounting')
        print ('B: Quick Estimate')
        print ('C: Distributors')

        User_Menu_Selection = input('Enter an option: ')

        if User_Menu_Selection == "A":
            print("Feature not available")


        elif User_Menu_Selection == "B":


            class Shoes:
                print('COMPANY MESSAGE', '\n' *5)
                print('--> Quick Estimates <--')

                def __init__(self, Model, Descpstr, price):
                    self.Model = Model
                    self.Descpstr = Descpstr
                    self.price = int(price)



            A100 = Shoes("A100", "Prada Flat Black", 100)
            A200= Shoes("A300", "Gucci Heel Black", 275)



            product_num = input('> Shoe Model(model number): ')
            product_size = input('> Shoe Size: ')
            product_qty = input('> Quantitiy: ')
            ship_zip_code = input('> Ship to Zip Code: ')




            if product_num == "A100" or product_num == "a100":
                order_calc = float(A100.price) * float(product_qty)
                print (float(order_calc))

            elif product_num == "A200" or product_num == "a200":
                order_calc = float(A200.price) * float(product_qty)
                print (float(order_calc))


            elif User_Menu_Selection == "C":
                print ("")
                print ("DISTRIBUTORS")
                print ("")
                print ("")
                print ("> Elderado's   Rep: Jack Reed   - Phone  # 1-888-562-2229 <")
                print ("> Friendly's   Rep: Roy Jack Jones   - Phone # 1-212-393-9939 <")
                print ("> Best Shoes Fort Wayne  Rep: Price Gouger   - Phone # 1-331-3832 <")
                print ("> The Rubber Maker   Rep: Crumble Crustipher   - Phone # 1-434-1919 <")




    variable_to_cause_loop = input ("For Main Menu Type Y" )

main()
```

Comment: Is your indentation exactly as it appears in the question (i.e. with the elif for "C" a peer of the `product_num` ifs rather than the other `User_Menu_Selection` ifs) or was that just a formatting error when pasting it in?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in @craig-meier's comment, unindent the `elif User_Menu_Selection == "C":` so it's in line with the "A" and "B" statements.

Also, you are using `input` so you have to type in `"A"` with quotes. You most likely want to use `raw_input` instead so you can just type `A` without the quotes.

Comment: The `input` vs `raw_input` thing only applies for python 2.x. In python 3 the original `input` was removed and `raw_input` was renamed to `input`.

Comment: I missed the tag on the question specifying the Python version. Thank you for the correction.

Comment: @CraigMeier in your experience, what is the advantage of raw_input?

Comment: @CoolJack1001 `raw_input` in python 2.x does what `input` does in python 3.x (i.e. what you want). In python 2.x, `input(...)` did what python 3.x would do as `eval(input(...))` (which is rarely a good idea -- just ask little Bobby Tables what happens when you execute unsanitized input).